# I want to write a template for my views, I am just struggling to make it

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-queryset

```
{'totals': 
<QuerySet [
{'trans_mode': 'Cash', 'month': datetime.date(2023, 1, 1), 'tot': Decimal('99.25')}, 
{'trans_mode': 'Cash', 'month': datetime.date(2023, 2, 1), 'tot': Decimal('161.25')}, 
{'trans_mode': 'Cash', 'month': datetime.date(2023, 3, 1), 'tot': Decimal('40.5')}, 
{'trans_mode': 'ENBD', 'month': datetime.date(2023, 1, 1), 'tot': Decimal('2215.72000000000')}, 
{'trans_mode': 'ENBD', 'month': datetime.date(2023, 2, 1), 'tot': Decimal('1361.66000000000')}, 
{'trans_mode': 'ENBD', 'month': datetime.date(2023, 3, 1), 'tot': Decimal('-579.130000000000')}, 
{'trans_mode': 'NoL', 'month': datetime.date(2023, 1, 1), 'tot': Decimal('107')}, 
{'trans_mode': 'NoL', 'month': datetime.date(2023, 2, 1), 'tot': Decimal('56')}, 
{'trans_mode': 'NoL', 'month': datetime.date(2023, 3, 1), 'tot': Decimal('-69.5')}, 
{'trans_mode': 'Pay IT', 'month': datetime.date(2023, 1, 1), 'tot': Decimal('0')}, 
{'trans_mode': 'SIB', 'month': datetime.date(2023, 1, 1), 'tot': Decimal('208.390000000000')}, 
{'trans_mode': 'SIB', 'month': datetime.date(2023, 2, 1), 'tot': Decimal('-3.25')}
]>}
```

above is the query set from Django views.

and my models.py

```
class Transactions(models.Model):
    TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('income', 'Income'),
        ('expense', 'Expense'),
    )

    PAYMENT_MODE_CHOICES = (
        ('cash', 'Cash'),
        ('enbd', 'ENBD'),
        ('nol', 'NOL'),
        ('payit', 'Pay IT'),
        ('sib', 'SIB'),
    )

    trans_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    trans_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date", db_index=True)
    trans_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES, verbose_name="Type")
    trans_main_category = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Main Category",
                                            related_name="transactions")
    trans_sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Sub Category",
                                           related_name="transactions")
    trans_mode = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=PAYMENT_MODE_CHOICES, verbose_name="Payment Mode",
                                  db_index=True)
    trans_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Amount")

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Transaction"
        verbose_name_plural = "Transactions"

    def __str__(self):
        amount = self.trans_amount
        if self.trans_type == 'expense':
            amount = -amount
            amount_str = f"${amount:,.2f}"

        return (
            f"Transaction ID: {self.trans_id}\n"
            f"Date: {self.trans_date}\n"
            f"Type: {self.trans_type}\n"
            f"Main Category: {self.trans_main_category}\n"
            f"Sub Category: {self.trans_sub_category}\n"
            f"Payment Mode: {self.trans_mode}\n"
            f"Amount: ${self.trans_amount:,.2f}"
        )
```

My views.py is below

```
def transaction_summary(request):
    totals = Transaction.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('trans_date')).values(
   'month', 'trans_mode').annotate(tot=Sum('trans_amount')).order_by()
    context = {
              'totals': totals
              }
     return render(request, 'transaction_summary.html', context)
```

I want to achieve the below, please suggest me a good way

| Trans Mode | Jan 2023 | Feb 2023 | Mar 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cash | 99.25 | 161.25 | 40.5 |
| ENBD | 2215.72 | 1361.66 | -579.13 |
| NoL | 107 | 56 | -69.5 |
| Pay IT |  |  |  |
| SIB | 208.39 | -3.25 |  |

Comment: convert datetime in string and Decimal in float. you already filtered data. Any Errors?

Comment: Share your models together with what you tried.

Comment: only logical errors, no actual errors. sorry for not adding the models.py,now I will add